# Dev C++ Boost v1.46.0 linker problems

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, time, linker

I'm using Dev C++ on Windows XP and I downloaded Boost package v 1.46.0 and installed it. I want to use it to make threads but I can't seem to compile even the simplest code.

My code:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
using namespace boost; 

void something()
{
}

int main ()
{
    thread rawr = thread(something);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile log:

```
.../Dev-Cpp/lib/libboost_thread.a(thread.o)(.text+0x3526):thread.cpp: undefined reference to `gettimeofday'
.../Dev-Cpp/lib/libboost_thread.a(thread.o)(.text+0x3551):thread.cpp: undefined reference to `_gmtime32'
.../Dev-Cpp/lib/libboost_thread.a(thread.o)(.text+0x393e):thread.cpp: undefined reference to `gettimeofday'
.../Dev-Cpp/lib/libboost_thread.a(thread.o)(.text+0x3966):thread.cpp: undefined reference to `_gmtime32'
.../Dev-Cpp/lib/libboost_thread.a(thread.o)(.text+0x3e9e):thread.cpp: undefined reference to `gettimeofday'
.../Dev-Cpp/lib/libboost_thread.a(thread.o)(.text+0x3ec9):thread.cpp: undefined reference to `_gmtime32'

.../Dev-Cpp/lib/libboost_thread.a(thread.o)(.text+0x533a):thread.cpp: undefined reference to `gettimeofday'
.../Dev-Cpp/lib/libboost_thread.a(thread.o)(.text+0x5365):thread.cpp: undefined reference to `_gmtime32'
.../Dev-Cpp/lib/libboost_thread.a(thread.o)(.text+0x57f0):thread.cpp: undefined reference to `gettimeofday'
.../Dev-Cpp/lib/libboost_thread.a(thread.o)(.text+0x581b):thread.cpp: undefined reference to `_gmtime32'
.../Dev-Cpp/lib/libboost_thread.a(thread.o)(.text$_ZN5boost9date_time6c_time6gmtimeEPKlP2tm[boost::date_time::c_time::gmtime(long const*, tm*)]+0x44):thread.cpp: undefined reference to `_gmtime32'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make.exe: *** [project.exe] Error 1

Execution terminated
```

I linked libboost_thread.a in project options but I guess I need something more?(What exactly?) Please help me fix this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'd suggest ditching Dev-C++. It's old, unmaintained crap, and includes an obsolete version of GCC. wxDev-C++ is marginal improvement, but there are better free IDEs (like Code::Blocks and MSVC Express) that come with more modern compilers.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, might try those out

Comment: I should probably add that the older your compiler is, the less likely it is to be supported by recent versions of Boost. Dev-C++ comes with a version of GCC that is going on **7 years old.**

Comment: Make sure that you also link the boost date time library.